# Mysql query error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to debug a php mysql script and i found the error in the query below

```
 SELECT `profile`.*,`extend`.* ,`online`.`hash` AS `online` FROM `skadate_profile` AS `profile` LEFT JOIN `skadate_profile_extended` AS `extend` USING( `profile_id` ) LEFT JOIN `skadate_profile_online` AS `online` USING( `profile_id` ) WHERE `profile`.`profile_id`!= 116 AND 1 AND `profile`.`profile_id` NOT IN ( SELECT `blocked_id` FROM `skadate_profile_block_list` WHERE `profile_id` =116 ) AND ( 16&IF( ISNULL(`match_religion`) OR `match_religion`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `match_religion` ) AND 16&IF( ISNULL(`religion`) OR `religion`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `religion` ) ) AND FIND_IN_SET('448','3,475,342,448') AND ( 16384&IF( ISNULL(`match_language_`) OR `match_language_`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `match_language_` ) AND 16384&IF( ISNULL(`language`) OR `language`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `language` ) ) AND ( 0xffffffffffffffff&IF( ISNULL(`sex`) OR `sex`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `sex` ) AND 1&IF( ISNULL(`match_sex`) OR `match_sex`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `match_sex` ) ) AND ( 1&IF( ISNULL(`match_resident_status`) OR `match_resident_status`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `match_resident_status` ) AND 7&IF( ISNULL(`resident_status`) OR `resident_status`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `resident_status` ) ) AND ( 8&IF( ISNULL(`match_occupation`) OR `match_occupation`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `match_occupation` ) AND 4294971400&IF( ISNULL(`occupation`) OR `occupation`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `occupation` ) ) AND ( 91&IF( ISNULL(`match_education`) OR `match_education`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `match_education` ) AND 1,28,92&IF( ISNULL(`education`) OR `education`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `education` ) ) AND ( `profile`.`status`='active' ) AND `profile`.`profile_id`!= 116 AND `profile`.`sex` != 1 LIMIT 0, 15
```

the query on being run in phpmyadmin gives the error 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) in the last part, i.e

```
IF( ISNULL(`education`) OR `education`=0, 0xffffffffffffffff, `education` )
```

any ideA how can this be fixed.. any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: If you pasted the exact query into this question, then I think the issue is that you have improper single quotes in your FIND_IN_SET function

Comment: Just dumped this query out and found an extra quote at `AND FIND_IN_SET('448',3,475,342,448') `

Comment: that is a typo.. it is AND FIND_IN_SET('448','3,475,342,448')

Comment: If you cannot  be bothered to format the query so we can actually read it WHY would we bother reading it?